# Android Facebook "Unable to get provider" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, facebook

My app was working fine - then today it wasn't.  I'm getting this error and I've tried all of the answers (Except creating a new project and copying over).

Any ideas on what could have happened?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cleanercoding.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

It's like facebook just happened to uninstall itself?  Not sure what to do at this point.

Here's my `build.gradle` file.  Not sure if it's even correct:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cleanercoding.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow, it's working again - I quit android studio, opened it back up, updated android studio and maven (suggested updates) and opened the project and built again...

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you havent initialized the SDK. Make sure it is initialized in your activity to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I too got same issue , I solved this issue by changing Facebook version in dependency.
**From**
`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0'` 
 to 
`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'`